# Angular - How can I define model for complex object?

Tags: angular

I have this object structure in angular:

```
   this.calendar = {
        "years": {
            2018: {
                "months":
                    0: {
                        "weeks":
                            1: {
                                "days": {
                                    1: {
                                        date: "2018-05-01", 
                                        is_valid: true,
                                        price: {'single': 21}
                                    },
                                    2: {
                                        date: "2018-05-02", 
                                        is_valid: true,
                                        price: {'single': 31}
                                    },
                                    3: {
                                        date: "2018-05-03", 
                                        is_valid: true,
                                        price: {'single': 231}
                                    },
                                    4: {
                                        date: "2018-05-04", 
                                        is_valid: true,
                                        price: {'single': 41}
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            2: {
                                "days": {
                                    1: {
                                        date: "2018-05-01", 
                                        is_valid: true,
                                        price: {'single': 21}
                                    },
                                    ...                          
                                }
                            },
                    },
                    1: {
                        "weeks":
                            ...
                    },
                    ...
            },
            2019: {
                ...
            }
    }
```

I want to define this as interface in model because the structure will most likely stay same (or will add a couple of new things in future).

calendar.model.ts

```
export interface calendar {
  ...
}
```

Is it possible to define such a complicated structure in the model in some meaningful and understandable way?

Comment: Yeah it is possible even more complex than that. Look into Array https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Comment: there is also a nice app https://app.quicktype.io/ or if you are using vscode a plugin https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=quicktype.quicktype that can help you out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interface could look like this:

```
interface calendar {
  years: {
    [year: number]: {
      months: {
        [month: number]: {
          weeks: {
            [week: number]: {
              days: {
                [day: number]: {
                  date: string,
                  is_valid: boolean,
                  price: {
                    [quantity: string]: number
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

I don't know if there actually will ever be another `price` other than `single`, so feel free to change that accordingly.

But note that the object you posted is not valid JSON. I just guessed that

```
 "months":
     0: {
```

acutally means

```
 "months": {
     0: {
```

etc, so this would be a valid assignment:

```
const data: calendar = {
  "years": {
    2018: {
      "months": {
        0: {
          "weeks": {
            1: {
              "days": {
                1: {
                  date: "2018-05-01",
                  is_valid: true,
                  price: { 'single': 21 }
                },
                2: {
                  date: "2018-05-02",
                  is_valid: true,
                  price: { 'single': 31 }
                },
                3: {
                  date: "2018-05-03",
                  is_valid: true,
                  price: { 'single': 231 }
                },
                4: {
                  date: "2018-05-04",
                  is_valid: true,
                  price: { 'single': 41 }
                }
              }
            },
            2: {
              "days": {
                1: {
                  date: "2018-05-01",
                  is_valid: true,
                  price: { 'single': 21 }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: You could, but please just create an interface per model structure. One for year, one for month, etc.

Comment: I think the only part that could maybe be worth extracting its own interface is the `day`-part.

Comment: Great, thanks so much! Yea the day part is a bit complex so I agree :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to split the declarations into smaller parts. This will be easier when you ever need to construct the data in smaller parts, i.e. add a single day.

```
export interface Calendar {
    years: Year[];
}

export interface Year {
    year: number;
    months: Month[];
}

export interface Month {
    month: number;
    days: Day[];
}

export interface Day {
    day: number
    date: string;
    is_valid: boolean;
    price: {
        single: number
    }
}
```

You can then declare the object as following:

```
const data: Calendar = {
    years: [{
        year: 2018,
        months: [{
            month: 0,
            days: [{
                day: 1,
                date: "2018-01-02",
                is_valid: true,
                price: { single: 21 }
            }]
        }]
    }]
};
```